# How to find the 5th degree Taylor polynomial about x = 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

**Question**

f(x) = ln$\frac {1+x^2}{1-x}$

How to find the 5th degree Taylor polynomial of f(x) about x = 0 without finding all derivatives of ln$\frac {1+x^2}{1-x}$ ? Is there a better way to find this?

Comment: Note:   It’s $\ln(1+x^2)-\ln(1-x)$; do you know the series for $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: Yes. I know, but how to combine two series together? $\ln(1+^2)$ and  $\ln(1-x)$

Comment: Can’t you simply subtract the polynomials?

Comment: Oh yeah, I will try. Thank you.

Comment: If you get an answer, you could post it; then you may get more feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to consider first that
$$\frac{x^2+1}{1-x}=1+x+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^n$$ and then take the logarithm of
$$\log(1+t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{t^n}{n} $$ with $t=x+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^n$ and use the binomial expansion stopping as soon as you find an exponent greater than $5$.

In fact, you could show that, if 
$$\log \left(\frac{x^2+1}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$$ the coefficients are simply
$$a_{2n}=\frac{1-2 \cos (\pi  n)}{2 n}\qquad \text{and}\qquad a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2 n+1}$$